# Unexpected output when incorrectly specified loop executed

Tags: r, loops, date, vector

Can someone help clarify what was being output when this for loop was originally specified (incorrectly)?

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-07"), by = "day")
```

**Original**:

```
for(mydate in (dates)) {
print(mydate)
}
```

**Original output** (what are these??):

```
[1] 19358
[1] 19359
[1] 19360
[1] 19361
[1] 19362
[1] 19363
[1] 19364
```

**Correct**:

```
for(mydate in 1:length(mydates)) {
  print(mydate)
}
```

**Desired output**:

```
[1] 1 
[1] 2 
[1] 3 .... etc
```

**What is the 19358, 19359 etc?** Some kind of weird index?

Comment: Try `dates - as.Date("1970-01-01")`, maybe it'll be clearer to you

Comment: Ooooooh epoch time ty. But why would it convert dates into that without me directly doing that? They werent in that format before.

Comment: Because that's how they are stored in R when their class is stripped. Try ```'class<-'(as.Date("2023-01-07"), NULL)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for loops use low level subsetting, ditching the class, like `.subset2()` would.

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-07"), by = "day")

# what your object is made of at the lower level
dput(dates)
#> structure(c(19358, 19359, 19360, 19361, 19362, 19363, 19364), class = "Date")

structure(c(19358, 19359, 19360, 19361, 19362, 19363, 19364), class = "Date")
#> [1] "2023-01-01" "2023-01-02" "2023-01-03" "2023-01-04" "2023-01-05"
#> [6] "2023-01-06" "2023-01-07"

# bracket subsetting
dates[[1]]
#> [1] "2023-01-01"

# low level subsetting, fetch element, ditch attributes of containing list/vector, attributes include class
.subset2(dates, 1)
#> [1] 19358
```

Comment: Ahhh so its just ditching the class/attributes bc of the way it uses low level subsetting. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, and btw the terms low level subsetting and bracket subsetting are mine, because I have not found in the doc how else to differentiate them, there might be another more official name for those.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `Dates`:

> Dates are represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates.

Therefore the "weird index" is the number of days in between itself and 1970-01-01. Removing the class of "Dates" using `unclass` will give you the same numbers.

```r
unclass(dates)
[1] 19358 19359 19360 19361 19362 19363 19364
```